# Getting a "Permission Denied" Error with my code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I need help in identifying the problem within my code. I was watching a Youtube video on how to get empty fields to automatically populate when selecting an option within my ComboBox.1.. I've followed the tutorial and replaced any related `Ranges()` within his video with the `Ranges()` within my spreadsheet.

I've tried re-naming my ranges to be exactly like his.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Shee")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Val(Me.ComboBox1.Value) = ws.Cells(i, "A") Then
            MsgBox Me.ComboBox1.Value
            Me.TextBox1 = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
            Me.TextBox1 = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
            Me.TextBox1 = ws.Cells(i, "D").Value
            Me.TextBox1 = ws.Cells(i, "E").Value
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Funds")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

I expect that when the user selects the a investment within my file, the other blank fields are automatically populated with the desired data.

Comment: It's a bit unclear exactly what your issue is... can you include a picture of what you want to happen and what *is actually* happening - or at least tell us in words. For example, I don't know if you want the vba to write to a `range (cell object)` when the combobox changes or if you want to update fields on the userform. That being said, I see you are setting `Me.TextBox1` to multiple values. Do you mean `Me.TextBox2` ... `3` and so on? Lastly, what line does the error occur on? Perhaps the sheet is protected?

Comment: Many of your Range/Row/Cell objects are not fully qualified and that will cause unexpected results. for example: `ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count)` does not mean the same thing as `ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count)` - in that case, `Rows` refers to the active sheet.

Comment: may be typo of `Me.TextBox1` for all the text boxes. make it ``Me.TextBox2` , `Me.TextBox3` , `Me.TextBox4` etc . Add `Next` to end For loop before End Sub.  If you are not comparing only numbers then remove `Val` from`Val(Me.ComboBox1.Value) `.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Guys!!

This is the video I was trying to get help from 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0Lr4KDny44

Basically I want the user to select a "Fund" From the Combobox within my UserForm, then have the three corrisponding blank textboxes below the selection to be populated with the relevant data. For Example, When the user selects "Westpac" the rating given to westpac which is found within my sheet is displayed. 

I know my explaination is pre S#it but I'll try to respond as clearly as possible.

Comment: **[1.]** You are missing a `Next i` in `ComboBox1_Change()`. A typo I guess? **[2.]** Which line are you getting the error? **[3.]** If you are selecting `Westpac` in Combobox which is a "String" then why `Val(Me.ComboBox1.Value)` to convert it to a number?

Comment: Unfortuantely, VBA Isn't telling me what is at fault. Just says

Comment: Can I see your Workbook? If yes, then can you upload it in a free file sharing site ans share the  link here?

Comment: BTW is there any other code anywhere else in your workbook?

Comment: Would you like to quickly share your E-mail? Ill save it quick then remove your comment

Comment: I can but it is not fair for other experts who are also trying to help :)  Please upload it to a free file sharing site and share the link here

Comment: https://gofile.io/?c=yQUynO

I hope this works.

Comment: Now I'm recieving a "For without Next" Error.

Comment: The answer is in my first comment. See Point **[1.]**  ;)

Comment: Where do I insert it Siddharth?

Comment: I can give you the answer but sicne you are learning, I recommend that you read [THIS](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) Now you tell me where it should be ;)

Comment: I placed it under the "End if" 

Thank you so so much Everyone Siddharth Rout Especially. You've made my learn progress a whole lot more enjoyable and worth while. 

Ill be sure to see you guys tomorrow for more help <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because you have set the `.RowSource` of the combobox to `Fundss`

[image]

When you set the `RowSource` property then you cannot use the `Additem` property and hence the code fails with `Permission Denied` on the line `Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Cells(i, "A").Value`

**Solution**

1. Either remove the `Fundss` from the rowsource and then use `Additem` **OR**
2. Do not add items to the combobox using `Additem`. Use only one them.

I noticed couple of other issues

1. You are missing a `Next i` in `ComboBox1_Change()`
2. You do not have `TextBox1`. You have `TB1`, `TB2` etc...
3. If you are selecting `Westpac` in Combobox which is a *String* then why `Val(Me.ComboBox1.Value)` to convert it to a *Integer*?